# Manipulate RegEx matches for computations in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, version

In C# it is easy to use RegEx like this

```
string pattern = "Version\\(\"(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+)\"\\)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string output = rgx.Replace(someInput, "Version $1.$2.$3.$4");
```

However I want to know how extract `$3`, increment it and write it back to the output. This is necessary for automated incrementation of the build number in my current project. I saw something concerning delegation of an evaluator but didn't read it in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`MatchEvaluator` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) to accomplish this:

```
string output = rgx.Replace(input, 
    m => String.Format("Version {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
          m.Groups[1].Value,
          m.Groups[2].Value,
          int.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value) + 1,
          m.Groups[4].Value));
```

Comment: +1 Equal to the one I was writing, down to the use of `string.format` :-)

Comment: @xanatos thanks! I started out with concatenation but `String.Format` was much cleaner :)